# How to show pagination from controller Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The question is not directly on how to show the pagination that much I'm aware but rather how to modify it so that I can show it here

```
public function create()
    {
        $leaves = Leave::latest()->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
        $pagination = Leave::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('leave.create',compact('leaves'),compact('pagination'));
    }
```

The create function here returns to a page where you can create and view all that you have created at the same time on a table but the table keeps getting bigger so I wanted to add pagination here but it seems this is not the correct way I tried adding the ->paginate(5) right after latest() of $leaves but it showed an error

Is there another way I can add the pagination, the one right now works but it shows the leaves of all users but I need it to only show of that specific user that's why I added the auth up but I think the one under for pagination is overriding it

Comment: can you show the error message?

Comment: It shows this 
```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in 
```
when I change it to this 
```
        $leaves = Leave::latest()->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->paginate(5)->get();
```

Comment: you can replace get() with paginate(5) and it should work.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me it's now showing only the 5 of that user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the get() method at the end of your leaves query you can simply call paginate(5).

```
$leaves = Leave::latest()->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Yeah just needed to wait 2 more minutes to accept the answer

Comment: `auth()->id()` for shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$leaves = Leave::latest('users')->limit(5)
```

you can specify the number of rows you want to get  limit(number)